# How to put function inside a class into thread? (C++ using Boost)

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, function, boost

I have a class with some functions like `printf("hello main thread");` and `printf("hello thread created inside class");`. Each can theoreticaly use class variables. How to put one of that functions into thread? (C++ using Boost libraries)

Comment: I am confused, what do you mean by *each can theoretically use class variables*?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: I guess he meant a "method"

Comment: What is putting a function into thread exactly?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: If I had to guess, I'd say that these (member) functions  cannot be `static` because they use non-static members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> thread_ptr;

class your_class : boost::noncopyable  {
public:
    void run();
    void join();
    void signal_stop();

private:
    void your_thread_func();
    thread_ptr thread_;
};

void your_class::run()
{
    thread_ = thread_ptr(new boost::thread(boost::bind<void>(&your_class::your_thread_func, this))); 
}
void your_class::join()
{
    if (thread_) {
        thread_->join();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at `boost::bind`.

```
class Class
{
  public:
    void method(const char*);
};

// instance is an instance of Class
boost::thread(boost::bind(&Class::method, &instance, "hello main thread"));
```

Should do it.

However, note that `boost::thread` has a constructor that already does this: see [this link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.multiple_argument_constructor).

So you can basically just do:

```
boost::thread(&Class::method, &instance, "hello main thread");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Boost.Bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/bind/bind.html) for that.

```
class Foo {
public:
    void someMethod(const std::string & text);
};

Foo foo;
boost::thread(boost::bind(&Foo::someMethod, &foo, "Text"));
```